# Can I trigger a latch solenoid valve using a stepper motor driver (A4988)?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, solenoid

I would like to turn on/off a solenoid valve like this one:

CLABER 90812
[image: CLABER 90812 solenoid valve]

From what I leaned googling around, it seems that it requires a positive/negative pulse to turn it on/off. In practice, I need an H-Bridge to be able to control it both ways. I have some A4988 stepper motor drivers lying around, so I am thinking to use one of them for this purpose.

[image: A4988 stepper motor driver schematic]

Is this possible or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Can you use an A4988 stepper driver to turn on/off a bistable valve?

Yes you could. However there are several problems:

1. You do not have the ability to sense the current state of the stepper output switches.
2. You would need multiple pulses to change the state (polarity) of each of the A/B outputs.
3. You can't use the A/B outputs to drive two valves independently.

Your connection diagram is workable where you would replace the stepper motor A winding for example with your bistable valve winding.

The output waveform when driving a stepper motor is like this:

[image]

Notice in this image that if you set the A4988 to full step, for each two Dir pulses it will change state from a +current to a -current. There is no position that has zero current flowing. This would probably overheat your valve coil.

If however you set the A4988 to Half-step, there is a point in the step cycle where the current through the coil is zero. This means you have to do multiple steps to get from +current to zero then at least one more to reverse the polarity of the drive current. There will be some differnces in the current flowing (2x70%, 1x100%) but I'd assume this would not be troublesome.

To set the A4988 to Half step you have to set the MS1,2,3 line as below:

[image]

The last problem to solve is how do detect the state of the A outputs to know when you get to zero current.
I'd suggest two back to back opto-isolators would do the trick and you could sense +current, -current and no-current as two signals back into your MCU.
Perhaps something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnnn9Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Edit:**
If you are willing to go a slightly more complicated software path, you can use the A4988 *Reset line and the DIR pin to avoid use of state sensing.

1. *Reset provides a known (Home) position (+/-70%) for the outputs. You can see this in the [A4988 datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J450/a4988_DMOS_microstepping_driver_with_translator.pdf) on Figure 10 and Table 2. For Half step and greater this represents 45 degrees.

[image]

2. In Home position P1=+70% and P2=-70% current. From this position you could step DIR=0 to get P1=0%. If you want this to be your actual Home (say valve in OFF position) then you'd need to be aware of the polarity of the valve wires.
3. From your software you can now step Dir=1 to get +70% or Dir=0 to get -70% current. This of course precludes the use of P2 since the states don't align.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation @jack. I have only one doubt regarding the state detection problem (knowing when the driver is providing no current to the coil). Let's suppose I am setting the A4988 to half step mode as you correctly suggested. Since the number of steps required to do one complete cycle is a constant, I should be able to understand the current output by only counting the steps I took previously. Am I wrong?

Comment: @keyblade95 ....added to answer. If you want to do step counting then you can use *Reset to get to a known position. Then you can use Step/Dir counting,

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but you might misunderstood the working principle. The solenoid valve isn't a motor that has a permanent magnet, rather an iron chunk. No matter in which direction the current is flowing you do always get the attraction force coil VS chunk. So your valve can be just opened, it closes itself by means of a spring when unpowered.

You can however use the stepper motor driver to control 2 valves. You configure it in full step mode, then each 4 steps the process is repeated :

- A: ON,OFF,ON,OFF
- B: OFF,ON,OFF,ON

Comment: It looks like this is a bistable valve, unless I misunderstand the meaning I think is might actually need a current reversal to latch it one way or the other. Unlike a normal solenoid.

Comment: Full step mode is probably going to overheat the valve. Most of these are pulse+ on, pulse- off.